# How to find the completion status of apify task run

Tags: apify

How do you find the completion status (success, failure, or aborted) of an apify task run?

```
const crawler = new PhantomCrawler({
        input,
        requestQueue,
        dataset,
    });

    await crawler.run();
```

or if you have the

```
"actorId": ${JSON.stringify(process.env.APIFY_ACTOR_ID || null)},
"taskId": ${JSON.stringify(process.env.APIFY_ACTOR_TASK_ID || null)},
"runId": ${JSON.stringify(process.env.APIFY_ACTOR_RUN_ID || null)},
```

I see no reference in SDK or API

https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/apify

https://docs.apify.com/api/v2#/reference/actors/actor-object/run-task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each run (actor or task) has its [status](https://docs.apify.com/actor/run) which you can get if you send the API call the [GET run](https://docs.apify.com/api/v2#/reference/actors/run-object/get-run) endpoint. When you call an actor or task, you get this run info back with its status.

The code inside doesn't need to know its own status because if the code can ask for it, the task or actor is of course in the "RUNNING" state.

Comment: I used the js api but requires two parameters. the web api only requires one. const run = await Apify.client.acts.getRun({
        actId: process.env.APIFY_ACTOR_ID,
        runId: process.env.APIFY_ACTOR_RUN_ID
    });

Comment: Again, I'm not sure in which context you need to check the status. I wrote an article on how to work with the API, maybe it will cover your use-case - https://help.apify.com/en/articles/3224035-run-actor-task-and-retrieve-data-via-api